# Expo : Select Multiple item of flatlist ( change style)

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to add a badge on a View ,by a TouchableOpacity on press.
The trouble is the animation work appears only on one element at a time and not on two or more simultaneously

Here the code :

Flatlist :

```
 <FlatList
    data={this.state.ReturnedArray}
    width='100%'
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
    renderItem={this.renderizza}
    extraData={this.state.activeItem}
/>
```

Render funtion :

```
 <View style={style.containerFlat}>
    <View style={style.containerFlat1}>
        <Text style={style.txt}>{item.name} {item.cognome}</Text>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={style.containerFlat2} onPress={() => this.badge(item.expoToken,index)}>
      {(this.state.activeItem === index) ? <Animated.View style={[style.animatedView, { opacity: this.state.fadeValue }]}><Text>ADDED</Text></Animated.View> : null} 
        <Text style={style.AvatarTxt}  >{acronym}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Badge function add Token into an array and lunch animation :

```
 badge(chiavi, index) {
    if ((this.state.SelectedUser).includes(chiavi)) {
        this.Nonanimate(index)  
        this.state.SelectedUser.splice(this.state.SelectedUser.indexOf(chiavi), 1)
    } else {
        this.state.SelectedUser.push(chiavi)
        this.animate(index)
    }

}
```

and the animation / NotAnimation :

```
 animate = (index) => {
    this.setState({
        activeItem: index,
    });
    Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 0
    }).start()
};

Nonanimate = index => {
    this.setState({
        activeItem: index,
    });
    Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 0
    }).start()
};
```

i'm wasting days on this trouble. Suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the function to solve this :

```
badge = chiavi => {
        //console.log(chiavi.item.expoToken)
        if ((this.state.SelectedUser).includes(chiavi.item.expoToken)) {
            // this.Nonanimate(index)
            this.state.SelectedUser.splice(this.state.SelectedUser.indexOf(chiavi.item.expoToken), 1)
        } else {
            this.state.SelectedUser.push(chiavi.item.expoToken)
            // this.animate(index)
        }

        chiavi.item.isSelect = !chiavi.item.isSelect;
        chiavi.item.selectedClass = chiavi.item.isSelect ?
            style.selected : style.containerFlat1;
        const index = this.state.ReturnedArray.findIndex(
            item => chiavi.item.user_id === item.user_id
        );
        this.state.ReturnedArray[index] = chiavi.item;
        this.setState({
            ReturnedArray: this.state.ReturnedArray,
        });
```

and Flatlist :

```
 <FlatList
                    data={this.state.ReturnedArray}
                    width='100%'
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.user_id.toString()}
                    renderItem={item => this.renderizza(item)}
                    extraData={this.state}
                />
```

Source : [Link here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-highlight-and-multi-select-items-in-a-flatlist-component-react-native-1ca416dec4b])